# Key vault for data factory V1?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I would like to know if there is a way to use Key Vault for Data Factory V1 ? I don't seem to find an answer on the web .

thanks , Adam .

Comment: Not that I know of. We had to inject all credentials when deploying the ADF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ability to store Linked Service credentials is only available in ADF V2:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault

We don't have plans to add it to V1.